# Images don't display on the product detail page

Tags: magento2

I installed Magento 2.2 on an Ubuntu virtual machine running on Virtual Box on Windows 10.  After installing Magento, I installed the sample data with `php bin/magento sampledata:deploy` and `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.  I also cleared my cache.

Most pages on my store display correctly, including the images.  However, when I go to the product detail page for any product, the place where the product image should be shows the spinner, and the spinner never gets replaced by the product image.

When I look at the browser console, I see the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 112
   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
   at getNodeData (scripts.js:87)
   at Array.map (<anonymous>)
   at scripts.js:117
   at HTMLDocument.apply (main.js:70)
   at fire (jquery.js:3232)
   at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
   at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
   at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
   at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:225)
```

My folders all have the writable attribute for the www-data group, and I have installed the gd extension.

How do I get my images to display correctly?

Comment: when you click on above error, what you are getting in console ? are you using custom theme ? is this issue is appearing in default luma theme ?

Comment: That error is what's appearing in the browser console (on Chrome; the error syntax is slightly different and less detailed in Firefox).  I'm using the default Luma theme.